# Загрузка аудиофайла в группу вконтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api

Подскажите, как загружать аудиофайлы в группу. Описанный в документации метод `audio.getUploadServer` возвращает ошибку: User authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth. Использовать другой токен не вижу смысла, так как видимо только по нему определяется куда будет загружен файл.

Есть ли решение проблемы через апи? Или проще добавить имитацию браузера и загружать через него.

Comment: Как описано в документации, токен должен быть от пользователя, а не от группы

Comment: Впрочем, как загружать аудиозаписи в группу, действительно непонятно

Comment: @andreymal, метод `audio.add` (копирует аудиозапись на страницу пользователя или группы) при указании параметра `group_Id`. Изначально надо загрузить в музыку юзера.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, нашел этот вариант на просторах интернета. Загружаю к себе, добавляю в группу. Теперь бьюсь над удалением записи со своей страницы. У вас нет решения?

Comment: @mikelsv, `audio.delete`, сразу после копирования в группу)

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, пробовал: Access denied: audio methods are unavailable.

Comment: @mikelsv, вот здесь непонятно, у вас есть права чтобы добавить аудиозапись и загрузить на сервер, а чтобы удалить нет?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, тут все не понятно. Задача на десять минут, решаю третий день. Кажется проще имитировать работу браузера, чем мучить это апи.
У меня токен пользователя получен для flash приложения.

Comment: @mikelsv, токен нужен от standalone-приложения

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, создал standalone, сделал токен, результат тот же. Для полного счастья вконтакт блокирует мои аудиозаписи созданные через синтезатор речи. Всвязи с обращением правообладателя.